# Dual-monitor problem NVIDIA, screens flickering (turning on/off)

Tags: linux, linux-mint, nvidia, graphics

I switched to NVIDIA drivers in Linux Mint 17.3 Cinnamon via Driver Manager in order to be able to play games. I am on NVIDIA 750M. The problem is, when I try to connect the second screen via DisplayPort (with resolution 2560x1440), both screens are turning on/off. This does not happen when I use Intel graphics.

Here is what I tried:

1. I added a PPA `ppa:graphics-drivers/ppa`. Updated `nvidia-352` via this PPA. Rebooted. Did not help.
2. I switched to `nvidia-361` in this PPA. Rebooted. Did not work.